# NativeScript Vue Modal in an AbsoluteLayout Frame

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have an `AbsoluteLayout` with a `Frame` and a `Notification`. The problem is when I use `this.$showModal(...)` the modal prompts over everything. **So I can't use my notification component when a modal is open.**

I want the modal to prompt within the `Frame` of ID #root.

Here is a working example of my issue: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=R3JBqZ&v=6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modal pages are quite different form normal pages, it won't respect your positions on screen.

If you are looking for in-app notifications, why don't you try [nativescript-cfalert-dialog](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-cfalert-dialog) or [nativescript-feedback](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-feedback) plugin.

Comment: it's not an issue of notification. I have several components that should be on top of a Modal. The only way to make it work is to duplicate these components in every modal...

Comment: If you want to show anything over modal dialog, the only option could be by using your own custom modal dialog.

Comment: Indeed! Thanks for the great plugins by the way ;-)